# java convert csv file encoding from Unicode to UTF-8

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

I have software which exports csv files with Unicode encoding.

When I trying to read those files I get words with white spaces and symbols.

I want to write an automation which will read a csv file with Unicode encoding and convert the file and the date to UTF-8.

I tried several ways I saw in here but it didn't work out.

*edit - the code*

```
    String csvFile = "csv path";
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ",";

try {

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
        String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this code and I tried the same code but with the line:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Thanks!

Comment: please add some code whatever you have tried so far..

Comment: If the font you are displaying the file's text in does not support the codepoints, you won't be better off with another UTF encoding for the same point. Try using a font that supports the codepoints in question.

Comment: I added the code. Thanks @VikrantKashyap